# Issue with Docker Desktop & Node Postgres connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

Hey there I've been banging my head on this issue and hoping somebody in the community can help.

I'm currently using windows 10 and had previously used Docker toolbox for my dev setup, after upgrading to Docker desktop I'm having issues.

I traditionally spin up a postgres db with a docker-compose file with the following:

```
postgres:
  container_name: cnc-matches
  image: postgres:12.1-alpine
  ports:
    - '5432:5432'
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: cnc-matches
    POSTGRES_USER: danku
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: cnc123
```

Using the command `docker-compose up -d`.

This appears to work, but when I attempt to connect to it from my application using the node pg library like this

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();

pool = new Pool({
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT
    });
```

I get error logs:

```
error: password authentication failed for user "danku"
```

The .env file for the app is using these values

```
DB_USER="danku"
DB_PASSWORD="cnc123"
DB_HOST="127.0.0.1"
DB_NAME="cnc-matches"
DB_PORT="5432"
```

I've tried manually adding a second superuser to the DB in case theres something wrong with the created one and swapped around env vars but its been the same end result.

I must be missing something weird here... any advice appreciated.

For references:
docker-compose file: https://github.com/dan-mcm/cnc-db/blob/master/db-setup/docker-compose.yaml
pg pool file: https://github.com/dan-mcm/cnc-db/blob/master/utils/dbQueries.js#L18

I also tried to use it in the format of a url like

```
STAGING_DB_URL="postgres://danku:cnc123@127.0.0.1:5432/cnc-matches"
```

But same errors.

As requested here are the logs from within the docker container

```
Attaching to cnc-matches

cnc-matches | ****************************************************

cnc-matches | WARNING: No password has been set for the database.

cnc-matches | This will allow anyone with access to the

cnc-matches | Postgres port to access your database. In

cnc-matches | Docker's default configuration, this is

cnc-matches | effectively any other container on the same

cnc-matches | system.

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | Use "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set

cnc-matches | it in "docker run".

cnc-matches | ****************************************************

cnc-matches | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".

cnc-matches | This user must also own the server process.

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".

cnc-matches | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".

cnc-matches | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | Data page checksums are disabled.

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok

cnc-matches | creating subdirectories ... ok

cnc-matches | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix

cnc-matches | selecting default max_connections ... 100

cnc-matches | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB

cnc-matches | selecting default time zone ... UTC

cnc-matches | creating configuration files ... ok

cnc-matches | running bootstrap script ... ok

cnc-matches | sh: locale: not found

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:29.110 UTC [31] WARNING: no usable system locales were found

cnc-matches | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok

cnc-matches | syncing data to disk ... ok

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | Success. You can now start the database server using:

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections

cnc-matches | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or

cnc-matches | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

cnc-matches | waiting for server to start....2021-03-10 16:43:29.856 UTC [36] LOG: starting PostgreSQL 12.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.2.0) 9.2.0, 64-bit

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:29.871 UTC [36] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:29.900 UTC [37] LOG: database system was shut down at 2021-03-10 16:43:29 UTC

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:29.906 UTC [36] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections

cnc-matches | done

cnc-matches | server started

cnc-matches | CREATE DATABASE

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | waiting for server to shut down...2021-03-10 16:43:30.175 UTC [36] LOG: received fast shutdown request

cnc-matches | .2021-03-10 16:43:30.193 UTC [36] LOG: aborting any active transactions

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:30.193 UTC [36] LOG: background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 43) exited with exit code 1

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:30.193 UTC [38] LOG: shutting down

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:30.231 UTC [36] LOG: database system is shut down

cnc-matches | done

cnc-matches | server stopped

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

cnc-matches |

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:30.294 UTC [1] LOG: starting PostgreSQL 12.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.2.0) 9.2.0, 64-bit

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:30.294 UTC [1] LOG: listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:30.294 UTC [1] LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:30.313 UTC [1] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:30.340 UTC [47] LOG: database system was shut down at 2021-03-10 16:43:30 UTC

cnc-matches | 2021-03-10 16:43:30.347 UTC [1] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: Remove all the `"` from your `.env` file and try again

Comment: gave that a go - same result

Comment: Can you post the container logs as well?

Comment: added logs to initial post Tarun

Comment: Can you try with user and password both as `postgres`

Comment: I have tried both with postgres - it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bunch of digging around I checked the ports and saw two legacy postgres installations locally v10 and v13 were being used by default overwriting the docker container that was being exposed on port 5432. To work around this I've changed the forwarded port on the docker container to access the DB via port 5444 instead.

Thanks all for the suggestions - very annoying to debug!